# Android : How to handle properly a problem (activities/service) AssetManager

Tags: android, architecture, service, android-activity

I'll try to be clear and brief:
I'd like to have an entity handling questions/answers in my game application.
For this, **I need to access to the assets folder** (to browse within ressource files)

**I need my handler to be accessible from different activities**.

My problem is that a "normal" class can't do 
AssetManager mngr=getAssets();

So for the moment I have several constructor for this java class (one per activity call), so my class can retrieve ressources from wherever I am (by going through the activity method)

I know it's not the way it's supposed to be. I looked up services, but I don't find the way to have a "global" service from where I can call function from whatever activity I'm in.

If someone understands my problem and can give me some advice about how to reorganize my app, it would be really appreciated!

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods, which are called in Activity, could be also called though Context class. So, you could pass activity Context(or better application Context) to your class:

```
class MyClass{
  MyClass(Context context){
     AssetManager mngr=context.getAssets();  
  }
}
```

In activity:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's gonna do the job!